# "Line 357: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end"

Tags: ruby

This is my code. can you please help me to understand the error 
"Line 357: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end"

I am new to Ruby. Read many tutorials and developed this code.

```
$guess=0 
$j=0 
$ans = ""


def questions(no)

 case no

  when 1
    puts "\nWhat is 1+1 ? "
    puts "\n\na) 2 \tb) 3\t c) 4\n"
    puts "\nInput your answer a or b or c: "
    ans = gets.chomp


    if ans.casecmp("A") == 0

       puts "\n\t\tWrong :o :o :o"   
       guess=guess+1 
       return 1


    else

       puts "\n\t\tCorrect!!!"       
       return 0

    end   



  when 2
    puts "\nWhat is a OS ? "
    puts "\n\na) XP\tb) PX\t c) UI\n"
    puts "\nInput your answer a or b or c: "
    ans = gets.chomp

    if ans.casecmp("A") == 0

       puts "\n\t\tWrong :o :o :o"   
       guess=guess+1 
       return 1


    else

       puts "\n\t\tCorrect!!!"       
       return 0

    end   

  when 3
    puts "\nWhat is 1+2 ? "
    puts "\n\na) 2 \tb) 3\t c) 4\n"
    puts "\nInput your answer a or b or c: "
     ans = gets.chomp

    if ans.casecmp("B") == 0

       puts "\n\t\tWrong :o :o :o"   
       guess=guess+1 
       return 1


    else

       puts "\n\t\tCorrect!!!"       
       return 0

    end   

   when 4
    puts "\nWhat is 1+3 ? "
    puts "\n\na) 2 \tb) 3\t c) 4\n"
    puts "\nInput your answer a or b or c: "
     ans = gets.chomp

    if ans.casecmp("C") == 0

       puts "\n\t\tWrong :o :o :o"   
       guess=guess+1 
       return 1


    else

       puts "\n\t\tCorrect!!!"       
       return 0

    end   

   when 5
    puts "\nWhat is 1+4 ? "
    puts "\n\na) 5 \tb) 3\t c) 4\n"
    puts "\nInput your answer a or b or c: "
     ans = gets.chomp

    if ans.casecmp("A") == 0

       puts "\n\t\tWrong :o :o :o"   
       guess=guess+1 
       return 1


    else

       puts "\n\t\tCorrect!!!"       
       return 0

    end   

  when 6
    puts "\nWhat is 1+5 ? "
    puts "\n\na) 2 \tb) 3\t c) 6\n"
    puts "\nInput your answer a or b or c: "
     ans = gets.chomp

    if ans.casecmp("C") == 0

       puts "\n\t\tWrong :o :o :o"   
       guess=guess+1 
       return 1


    else

       puts "\n\t\tCorrect!!!"       
       return 0

    end   

  when 7
    puts "\nWhat is 1+6 ? "
    puts "\n\na) 2 \tb) 7\t c) 4\n"
    puts "\nInput your answer a or b or c: "
     ans = gets.chomp

    if ans.casecmp("B") == 0

       puts "\n\t\tWrong :o :o :o"   
       guess=guess+1 
       return 1


    else

       puts "\n\t\tCorrect!!!"       
       return 0

    end   

  when 8
    puts "\nWhat is 1+7 ? "
    puts "\n\na) 2 \tb) 8\t c) 4\n"
    puts "\nInput your answer a or b or c: "
     ans = gets.chomp

    if ans.casecmp("B") == 0

       puts "\n\t\tWrong :o :o :o"   
       guess=guess+1 
       return 1


    else

       puts "\n\t\tCorrect!!!"       
       return 0

    end   

  when 9
    puts "\nWhat is 1+8 ? "
    puts "\n\na) 9 \tb) 3\t c) 4\n"
    puts "\nInput your answer a or b or c: "
     ans = gets.chomp

    if ans.casecmp("A") == 0

       puts "\n\t\tWrong :o :o :o"   
       guess=guess+1 
       return 1


    else

       puts "\n\t\tCorrect!!!"       
       return 0

    end   

  when 10
    puts "\nWhat is 1+9 ? "
    puts "\n\na) 10 \tb) 3\t c) 4\n"
    puts "\nInput your answer a or b or c: "
     ans = gets.chomp

    if ans.casecmp("A") == 0

       puts "\n\t\tWrong :o :o :o"   
       guess=guess+1 
       return 1


    else

       puts "\n\t\tCorrect!!!"       
       return 0

    end  

  end

end




def check()

    case guess

        when 1

             puts "\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t       _|_"

        when 2
             puts "\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t__________"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|"
             puts "\n\t\t\t       _|_"


        when 3
             puts "\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t__________" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        |" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        O" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t       _|_" 

        when 4
             puts "\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t__________" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        |" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        O" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|       \\|/" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t       _|_" 

        when 5
             puts "\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t__________" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        |" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        O" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|       \\|/" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        |" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t       _|_" 

        when 6
             puts "\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t__________" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        |" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        O" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|       \\|/" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        |" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|       / \\" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|     --------" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|       |  |" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|       |  |" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t       _|_" 
             puts "\n\n\t\t\t\t\tOne Chance Left-> :) " 

        when 7
             puts "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t!!!The Man is Hanged!!!" 
             puts "\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t__________" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        |" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        0" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|       \\|/" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|        |" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|       / \\" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t\t|" 
             puts "\n\t\t\t       _|_" 
             puts "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Man Died :o :o :o" 
             puts "\n\n\n\t\t\t\t    !!!Game Over!!!" 

        else
             puts "\n\t\t\t\tProceed Press Enter->" 

    end
end



    puts "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" 
    puts "\n\t\t\t\t-------------------------" 
    puts "\n\t\t\t\t|                       |" 
    puts "\n\t\t\t\t|  !!!HangMan Game!!!   |" 
    puts "\n\t\t\t\t|                       |" 
    puts "\n\t\t\t\t-------------------------" 
    puts "\n\n\nRules: " 
    puts "\n------" 
    puts "\n\n1. You have 10 Questions." 
    puts "\n\n2. You have 7 Chances." 
    puts "\n\n3. For every Wrong Answer Man will be stepped towards hanging :O :O :O " 
    puts "\n\n4. Answer all the 10 questions before the man hangs!!!" 
    puts "\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t    !!!Best of Luck!!!" 
    puts "\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t      Game designed by DHANABHARATHI,PEC"     

    for i in 1..10 do          

        k=0       
                j=10-i 
        puts "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#{j} Questions More" 
        k = questions(i) 

        if k==1 
            check 
        end

        break if guess>=7       
        i=i+1
                end


    end //LINE 357

    if guess<7
    puts "\n\t\t\t\t     You Won!!! Congrats!!!" 
    puts "\n\t\t\t\t     ________   ______________" 

    else
    puts "\n\n\n\t\t\t\t       You lose!!!" 
    end
```

Please teach me how to clear the error and make my code working

Comment: I don't see any code. Please post code, don't make people track it down. If it's too long, then expend the effort to isolate the problem spot, even if by trial and error. And recognize there's a big difference between "can answer", and "will anger", particularly when the question is just "I get this error note go look at it and fix it."

Comment: @DaveNewton rolled back to include the link. I'll copy it in, and perhaps do some clean up.

Comment: I'd recommend it; there are large chunks of duplicated code, and when you get further along, you'll see opportunities to use classes to avoid other duplications.

Comment: (My original comment should have read "will answer", autocorrect.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry sir I understood How I have been harsh in my question :( sorry

Comment: I am using codepad.org 
this line of code is not accepting :( :( :( I read in tutorial that this is working but it is not working get_character 

"ans = gets.chomp" any other alternatives for this . I am getting input a single character a or b or c .. I have also tried ans =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an end on line 354 that I don't think should be there, change this:

```
    break if guess>=7       
    i=i+1
    end


end
```

to this:

```
    break if guess>=7       
    i=i+1


end
```

Comment: Why cant I enter the input .. My program gets struck in "ans = gets.chomp"

Comment: I am using codepad.org this line of code is not accepting :( :( :( I read in tutorial that this is working but it is not working get_character "ans = gets.chomp" any other alternatives for this . I am getting input a single character a or b or c .. I have also tried get_character it is also not working